# how to get and print tokens from google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing a apps on google drive , and i want to try the android-quickstart on google web page ,i have follow the sample code, when i try to get  the tokens from it, it has errors,here's are my codes

```
 protected void  onActivityResult  (final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) { switch (requestCode) {
case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
    String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);  
    Toast.makeText(this," Account Name = "+accountName,3000).show(); //show my account name
    if (accountName != null) {
      credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
     service = getDriveService(credential);          
     String token = data.getStringExtra("token");
      System.out.println(token); 
}
}
 break; 
 case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
  getDriveContents();

  } else {
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
  }
  break;
}   
}
```

and the logcat shows

> 02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.testfyp/com.example.testfyp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3162)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3205)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:138)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at com.example.testfyp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:88)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5192)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3158)
>   02-07 13:04:24.830: E/AndroidRuntime(13906):    ... 11 more

i don't know how to fix it